# How to change the button text to a number from an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm working on  a small project and I have an array with 4 numbers. I want to display them on 4 buttons. I tried this code but it doesn't seem to be working. Do you have any ideas where I could make a mistake ?

```html
<div id="results">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-result" id="button1">Result</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-result" id="button2">Result</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-result" id="button3">Result</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-result" id="button4">Result</button>
</div>
```

```js
var rnum1 = generateRandomNumber1();
var rnum2 = generateRandomNumber2();
var rnums = [rnum1, rnum2];
var rnumsSort = rnums.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a
});
//pass the random numbers to the function
var data = generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult(rnumsSort[0], rnumsSort[1]);
//data=["+", [5]]
var operator = data[0];
var corResult = data[1][0][0];
var ranResult = [data[1][0][1], data[1][0][2], data[1][0][3]];
var allResults = data[1][0];
var sortAllResults = allResults.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});
var buttonText = buttonResult();

function buttonResult() {

  for (var i = 0; i < sortAllResults.length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".button-result").textContent = sortAllResults[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to set the `textContent` of a NodeList in this line:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".button-result").textContent= sortAllResults[i];
```

You need to select the index of the current button:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".button-result")[i].textContent= sortAllResults[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

just a small working example how you can fill your Buttons.

```js
const randomNumber = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
[...myArray] = randomNumber.toString();

const insertResult = (origArray) => {
  const myButtons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('button-result'));
  origArray.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  myButtons.forEach((button, index) => button.textContent = myArray[index]);
};

insertResult(myArray);
```

```html
<div id="results">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-result" id="button1">Result</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-result" id="button2">Result</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-result" id="button3">Result</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-result" id="button4">Result</button>
</div>
```